# Is there currently a problem with border crossings to Ukraine?

Tags: borders, ukraine, event-based-effects

Given the [current situation](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/ukraine-repeals-anti-protest-laws-after-pm-resigns-1.2513611) in Ukraine are there problems with crossing of the Ukrainian borders?  In general and for westerners in particular.

Comment: @hippietrail: yes things can change daily now; on the one hand 40+ million people country still tries to move on, on the other hand there is crisis in progress, and a bit of unrest.

Comment: Somehow I had missed this question when it was fresh. Ukraine has been on my list for my next trip so fingers crossed things work out. Hopefully we can keep this thread up to date...

Comment: @hippietrail Sit tight.  Things are just about to get interesting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because event is no longer in effect.

Comment: @Karlson no 'historical' relevance ?

Comment: @blackbird While there is historical relevance there is no reason to get new answers since this particular event will not affect current or future travel plans.  And it is still possible to read a locked or closed question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am Ukrainian, just took a weekend trip to Norway (flying from/to KBP) and there were no issues whatsoever at border in either direction.

**[update]**

Well, that escalated quickly...

According to news due to tension with Russia border with them is "nearly locked down". 
According to reports:

- Russians coming are getting denied entry in droves
- Ukrainians going are getting asked for things like proof of funds for stay and medical insurance, which isn't typical procedure.

Comment: Russians are turned away in case they are suspected to come to participate in acts of disorder; Russia on the other hand started stricter enforcement of their legislation as for proving one has funds for Russian stay. I know a person who went to Moscow by train with no issues, but in general I'd rather say to stay away from Ukraine for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Two days ago, demonstrants have blocked border crossings to Poland. Some were totally blocked (for westerners and non-westerners likewise) and others were only blocked for trucks. That was a very temporary and isolated action. In the meantime [all the crossings are clear again](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/02/21/us-ukraine-crisis-poland-borders-idUSBREA1K0FJ20140221).